# Python - How to prevent for loop overwriting same excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, loops, for-loop, overwrite

Recently I been working on my small project that is auto generating work hours spreadsheets for me. It's been working well for me only but when I want to generate multiple worksheets (later on refereed as sheet) and or generate multiple spreadsheets It overwrites the old one.

For opening, editing and generating the spreadsheet I'm using openpyxl lib.

I have tried moving save part and generate part outside of the loops and etc. but none of that helped me.

Question is how do I prevent for loop from overwriting the file and instead of that generating the new one ?

Here's the main piece of that software down below.

```
cols = [2, 3, 4, 12]
row = 9
hrs = 0
nhrs = 0


for worker in workers:
    sheet.title = ('{} {}'.format(worker.name, worker.surename))
    for day, hday in itertools.zip_longest(days, holidays):
            if day.weekday() <= 4 and day not in holydays:
                sheet.cell(row=row, column=cols[0]).value = '08:00'
                sheet.cell(row=row, column=cols[1]).value = '16:00'
                sheet.cell(row=row, column=cols[2]).value = '8 h'
                hrs += 8
                row += 1
            elif day.weekday() > 4 and day not in holidays:
                sheet.cell(column=cols[0], row=row).value = ''
                row += 1
            elif day in holidays:
                sheet.cell(column=cols[3], row=row).value = '8 h'
                nhrs += 8
                row += 1

    sheet.cell(column=cols[2], row=40).value = str(hrs) + ' h'
    sheet.cell(column=cols[3], row=40).value = str(nhrs) + ' h'

workbook.save('SPREADSHEET_{}.xlsx'.format(native_month))
print('Done')
```

Thanks in advance !

---

Edit from comment:

```
# native_month for the workbook name is provided by this function applied to a 1-12 
def month_name_native(month): 
    months = ["Unknown", "Januar", "Februar", "Mart", "April", "Maj", "Jun", 
              "Jul", "August", "Septembar", "Oktobar", "Decembar" ] 
    return months[month].upper()
```

Comment: Where is `native_month` defined? Is it changing?

Comment: Your code is incomplete regarding [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - no includes, no workbook-creation , no adding of sheets to the workbook , .....

Comment: Native month is string that is returned from fucntion (method) month_name_native that takes month as integer and returns month name in my native language (serbian). Please find code snippet further down in comment:

    def month_name_native(month):
    months = ["Unknown",
              "Januar",
              "Februar",
              "Mart",
              "April",
              "Maj",
              "Jun",
              "Jul",
              "August",
              "Septembar",
              "Oktobar",
              "Decembar"
              ]
    return months[month].upper()

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want for each worker a new spreadsheet, right?

What you are currenctly doing is that you use the same sheet object over and over again, thus it gets overwritten. You have to create a new sheet inside the for loop for each worker. This should do:

```
cols = [2, 3, 4, 12]
row = 9
hrs = 0
nhrs = 0
workbook = Workbook()  # assuming you imported openpyxl with *, else adjust

for worker in workers:
    sheet = workbook.create_sheet('{} {}'.format(worker.name, worker.surename)) 
    for day, hday in itertools.zip_longest(days, holidays):
           if day.weekday() <= 4 and day not in holydays:
               sheet.cell(row=row, column=cols[0]).value = '08:00'
               sheet.cell(row=row, column=cols[1]).value = '16:00'
               sheet.cell(row=row, column=cols[2]).value = '8 h'
               hrs += 8
               row += 1
           elif day.weekday() > 4 and day not in holidays:
               sheet.cell(column=cols[0], row=row).value = ''
               row += 1
           elif day in holidays:
               sheet.cell(column=cols[3], row=row).value = '8 h'
               nhrs += 8
               row += 1

    sheet.cell(column=cols[2], row=40).value = str(hrs) + ' h'
    sheet.cell(column=cols[3], row=40).value = str(nhrs) + ' h'

workbook.save('SPREADSHEET_{}.xlsx'.format(native_month))
print('Done')
```

Comment: nice guesstimate - should help the OP to fix his. unfortunately this code in itself will not run as neither `workers`, `days` nor `holidays` was specified by the OP. sad.

Comment: Yes that Is correct mate. Only thing is that I'm loading premade spreadsheet (because of styling). So basically what I want to achive is load the same template worksheet over and over again and save it as individual file and or worksheet.

Comment: I see. Have you tried `target = workbook.copy_worksheet(source)`

Comment: I used `target = workbook.copy_worksheet(source)` now in for loop and it generated new worksheets as intended. Only problem left is how to reset row for each worker because now in sheet for second worker it starts at row 39 or so..

Comment: that is quite trivial. instead of `row` use another variable that tracks the rows for each worker (e.g. `addRow+=1`) and that is initialized to 0 at the beginning of the worker for-loop. Then use `row=row+addRow` instead of `row=row` in the .cell method. PS: Upvoting my answers/comments appreciated ;-)